# I want to deploy my React app to Plesk Obsidian 18.0.54

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have made a build and placed it in folder with root directory. But still I am getting 404 error

Tried everything but I think I don't know the steps

Before building build is it some necceesary steps to perform then please mention them so I can deploy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the files inside the build, not the build folder itself in that Plesk folder. Also create a `.htaccess` file and put it along those files as well. This is needed for react to handle routes.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```